# How to iterate over array in ionize-cms with codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using Ionize cms for the back end of my site and I want to create my own Tags - for passing data from my own tables. I've followed [This](http://doc.ionizecms.com/en/tutorials/build-one-module-part-4) tutorial to create custom tags, and by that - passing data to views, but I keep getting error:

**Tag missing: demo, scope: .**

Here is my view :

```
<ul>
    <ion:demo:details> 
        <li><ion:detail field="user_name" /></li>
    </ion:demo:details>
</ul>
```

And here are the changes I've added to TagManager.php

```
 public static $tag_definitions = array
    (
    // <ion:demo:authors /> calls the method “tag_details”
    "demo:details" =>      "tag_details",
    "demo:details:detail" =>    "tag_detail",
    );
```

I've also tried to create a simple codeigniter controller and pass the data with view() and to do something like :

```
<ul>
   <?php foreach($details as $detail): ?>
     <li>
     <?php echo $detail['name'] ?>
     </li>
    <?php endforeach ;?>
</ul>
```

But I'm getting undefined error of `$details`.

Comment: Will you please show your controller?

Comment: B. Desai, Thanks, Ionize cms has 2 main controllers page & article, when a page i created in DB it's being passed through them, so the only way to pass variables to view is with TagManager - like in the tutorial - in my post....my problem is that i can't understand how to iterate over variables.....

Answer (score 5):

Changed the tags and now it's good.

```
<?php
class TagManager_Data extends TagManager

{
   public static $tag_definitions = array(

      "authors" => "tag_authors",
      "authors:author" => "tag_author",
   );

    public static function index(FTL_Binding $tag)
   {
      $str = $tag->expand();
      return $str;
   }

   public static function tag_authors(FTL_Binding $tag)
   {
      $str = '';
      $authors = [["name" => 'josh', "foo" => 'josh'], ["name" => 'joshjosh', "foo" => 'josh'], ["name" => 'josh', "foo" => 'josh']];
      foreach($authors as $author) {
         $tag->set('author', $author);
         $str.= $tag->expand();
      }

      return $str;
   }

   public static function tag_author(FTL_Binding $tag)
   {
      $field = $tag->getAttribute('field');
      if (!is_null($field)) {
         $author = $tag->get('author');
         if (!empty($author[$field])) {
            return self::output_value($tag, $author[$field]);
         }

         return self::show_tag_error($tag, 'The attribute <b>"field"</b> is not set');
      }
   }
}
```